# Path issue to root directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to run the [`coin_flip_traders_v1.0.py`](https://github.com/darwinex/dwx-zeromq-connector/blob/master/v2.0.1/python/examples/template/strategies/coin_flip_traders_v1.0.py) script from the Darwinex ZeroMQ Python library here -> https://github.com/darwinex/dwx-zeromq-connector/tree/master/v2.0.1/python

However, I am having some trouble with the path that it says at the top of the file to point to the root directory.

I have changed it to `_path = '../../..'`  Which should take me to the project root. However I get the error:

> File
>   "/Users/Al/Desktop/Trading/examples/template/strategies/base/DWX_ZMQ_Strategy.py",
>   line 20, in  os.chdir(_path) NameError: name '_path' is not defined

I then changed the path for the `DWX_ZMQ_Strategy.py` to **`_path = '../../../..'`**

I then get the error:

> File
>   "/Users/Al/Desktop/Trading/examples/template/strategies/base/DWX_ZMQ_Strategy.py",
>   line 24, in  from api.DWX_ZeroMQ_Connector_v2_0_1_RC8 import
>   DWX_ZeroMQ_Connector ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'

I am thinking that it has something to do with the way I am setting the path to the root directory, but not sure where I am going wrong.

If it helps, I am running python 3.6.8 and the command I am executing to run the script is **`exec(open("coin_flip_traders_v1.0.py").read())`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*The problem is not a ZeroMQ-related problem.*</sup>

For diagnosing the rest, the successful file-system tree-navigation, start with using this:

```
print( "DEBUG: now uses this directory-tree {0:} node".format( os.getcwd ) )
...
os.chdir( anyMaskForRelativeOrAbsoluteTreeMOVE ) # no ~-"expansions"
...
print( "DEBUG: now uses this directory-tree {0:} node".format( os.getcwd ) )
```

Also kindly note, you must reach such a directory, where the API was installed, not the "root"-directory of the whole filesystem. Check where your DWX installation is actually located and direct the `os.chdir()`-move to reach that point.